# Reworking Custom Post Type Array for Film & Event Calendar

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've inherited a project that lists films & events (custom post type) on a ticket page by date/time. Now I need to rework the PHP so that the page is listed by movie title instead. Unfortunately, I struggle when dealing with arrays.

```
<?php
    
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => array('films', 'events'),
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$items = get_posts($args);
$yesterday = strtotime('now - 1 day');
$twoweeks = strtotime('now + 2 weeks');
$days = array();
$dayIndex = 0;

foreach ($items as $item) :
    $showtimes = get_field('showtimes', $item->ID);
    if ($showtimes) {
        foreach ($showtimes as $showtime) {
            if (strtotime($showtime['show_date']) > $yesterday && strtotime($showtime['show_date']) < $twoweeks) {
                while( have_rows('showtimes', $item->ID) ): the_row();
                    $eventDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_sub_field('show_date', $item->ID)));
                    if ( strtotime(get_sub_field('show_date')) > strtotime('now - 1 day') ) :
                        while( have_rows('show_times') ): the_row();
                            $days[$eventDate][] = array(
                                'id' => $item->ID,
                                'name' => $item->post_title,
                                'type' => $item->item_type,
                                'time' => get_sub_field('time'),
                                'date' => $eventDate
                            );
                        endwhile;
                        break;
                    endif;
                endwhile;
            }
        }
    } else if ($item->post_type == 'events') {
        $eventDate = strtotime(get_field('date', $item->ID));
        if ($eventDate > $yesterday && $eventDate < $twoweeks) {
            $days[date('Y-m-d', $eventDate)][] = array(
                'id' => $item->ID,
                'name' => $item->post_title,
                'type' => $item->item_type,
                'time' => get_field('time', $item->ID)
            );
        }
    }
    ksort($days);
endforeach;

foreach($days as $date => $times) {
    if(usort($times, 'SortDateTimes')) {
        $days[$date] = $times;
    }
}

if ($days) {

?>
<form>
    <select class="form-select" name="showing_dates">
    <?php foreach($days as $date => $times) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $date; ?>" data-day="<?php echo $date; ?>"><?php echo date('l, F d', strtotime($date)); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
<?php $dayIndex = 1;
foreach($days as $date => $times) : ?>
    <div class="showing-day <?php echo $dayIndex == 1 ? 'current' : ''; ?>" data-day="<?php echo $date; ?>">
        <?php foreach($times as $showing) :
            // DISPLAY MOVIES BY SHOW TIMES
        endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php $dayIndex++;
endforeach; ?>
```

This outputs an array based on the individual movie show times for each date:

```
[2023-05-31] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11892
                    [name] => MOVIE TITLE #1
                    [type] => Film
                    [time] => 12:30pm
                    [date] => 2023-05-31
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11896
                    [name] => MOVIE TITLE #2
                    [type] => Film
                    [time] => 1:00pm
                    [date] => 2023-05-31
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11892
                    [name] => MOVIE TITLE #1
                    [type] => Film
                    [time] => 3:30pm
                    [date] => 2023-05-31
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11896
                    [name] => MOVIE TITLE #2
                    [type] => Film
                    [time] => 4:00pm
                    [date] => 2023-05-31
                )
...
```

Instead -- I need to generate an array based on the movie title (no duplicates). And then list the (multiple) show times under each title. All while leaving the array in place for generating the date dropdown.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: _"All while leaving the array in place for generating the date dropdown."_ - that doesn't make sense, when you want to switch from grouping by date, to grouping by title. Just keep the dates in a second array ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a new array by iterating over the `$days` array.

Here’s my idea of what the code would be (untested):

```php
$films = array();

foreach ( $days as $day => $films_on_day ) {
    foreach ( $films_on_day as $film ) {
        if ( ! isset( $films[ $film[‘name’] ] ) ) {
            $films[ $film[‘name’] ] = array(
                ‘id’    => $film[‘id’],
                ‘type’  => $film[‘type’],
                ‘times’ => array(),
            );
        }

        if ( ! isset( $films[ $film[‘name’] ][‘times’][ $film[‘date’] ] ) ) {
            $films[ $film[‘name’] ][‘times’][ $film[‘date’] ] = array();
        }

        $films[ $film[‘name’] ][‘times’][ $film[‘date’] ][] = $film[‘time’];
    }
}
```